# How to get list of all subscribers in ManyChat API

Tags: rest, manychats

I want to start using ManyChat API. I see on their help page here https://api.manychat.com/swagger many functions to find users by name or id etc (getinfo, findbyname... ).

But I need a list of all subscribers (names and email addresses)

which function do I need?

Thanks!

Comment: any ideas anybody? btw why does the manychat tag have an "s" at the end?